# how to make a channel in geosoft using python gxpy module

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is this code correct in order to make a new channel? everytime i try it i dont see a result when i open the gdb in oasis montaj

Note that the first block I also tried to tie in data from a csv

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geosoft.gxapi as gxapi
import geosoft.gxpy.gx as gx
import geosoft.gxpy.gdb as gxdb
import geosoft.gxpy.utility as gxu
gx = gx.GXpy()

f = open('BOW_FEON_Cosmic.csv','r')

ch = f.readline().strip().split()
npd = np.loadtxt(f,delimiter=',',dtype=float)
Raltlc = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter= ',')

gdb = gxdb.Geosoft_gdb.new('BOW_GDB_Cosmic.gdb')
for line in gdb.list_lines():
npd,ch,fid = gdb.write_line('Raltlc')
gxdb.Channel.new(gdb,'Raltlc',dtype=np.float)
```

I also tried using the follwing when the previous method did not work

```
gxc = gx.GXpy()

def Cosmic_test():
gxdb.Geosoft_gdb.new("BOW_GDG_COSMIC.gdb", overwrite=True)
gxdb.Channel.new("BOW_GDG_COSMIC.gdb","LineN")
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a new channel in a Geosoft GDB using the Python GX API, you can use the `gxdb.Channel.new()` method. Here's an example code snippet that shows how to create a new channel called "my_new_channel" in a Geosoft GDB called "my_gdb.gdb":

```
import geosoft.gxapi as gxapi
import geosoft.gxpy.gdb as gxdb

# create a new Geosoft GDB
gdb = gxdb.Geosoft_gdb.new("my_gdb.gdb", overwrite=True)

# create a new channel in the GDB
ch = gxdb.Channel.new(gdb, "my_new_channel", dtype=gxapi.GS_DOUBLE)
```

In this example, the `dtype` parameter specifies the data type of the channel (in this case, a `GS_DOUBLE`, which corresponds to a double-precision floating-point number).

Once you create a new channel, you can write data to it using the `gdb.write_channel_data()` method. For example:

```
# write data to the new channel
data = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
gdb.write_channel_data("my_new_channel", data)
```

Note that in your code example, you're using the `gx.GXpy()` class to create a GX context object (`gx`). However, you don't need to do this to create a new channel in a Geosoft GDB. Instead, you can use the `gxdb` module directly (as shown in the example above).

Comment: Thank you very much for this, the gdb was created but still gave me some issues,  here is the return i got when i ran it in Pycharm:
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'.
`np.float` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `float` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20;  Did you mean: 'cfloat'?

Comment: If the error arises in user code, simply replace each np.float with float. If the error arises in the code of the geosoft module, try upgrading the module with `pip install geosoft --upgrade`, maybe you are running an old versioon that is not compatible with the current numpy. If this still does not work, you can try downgrading your numpy to a version below 1.20.